# re-setting all users points field to 0

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to set every user's points field ("profile.points") to 0 when I click a button. I'm trying to do this in a Meteor.methods function and am finding it hard to see the users collection as it returns a whole bunch of gibberish. Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried to at least display and exclude certain fields but no luck so far.

```
      Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'profile.points': 1, 'services': 0}})
```

Comment: So when you click the button, it resets the points of that particular user to 0 or all available user's points to 0? Since you're using find, it returns a cursor for you to iterate over. That's why you see "gibberish". If you want to see the actual data, use something like ```Meteor.users.find({...}).fetch();``` or use ```findOne({...})``` to see an individual document.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, and yeah I'm wanting to reset all users points to 0 onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@blueren is correct about displaying the contents of a collection intelligently - `.fetch()` will convert the *cursor* into an *array* which is readable.

To implement your points reset execute the following in your server method:

```
Meteor.users.update({'profile.points': {$ne: 0}},{$set: {'profile.points': 0}},{multi: true});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works really well. I heard from someone "you should avoid using profile for pretty much all usercases. It's mostly a legacy field and offers essentially no benefits while potentially compromising security." Is that true by any chance aswell?

Comment: I think it's just important to know that it is published by default and then deal accordingly.